# Any suggested book or websites about the subjects of Permutations and Group Actions on Sets

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Can someone tell me a source where there are questions (possibly with a solution manual) about the subjects of Permutations and Group Actions on Sets.

Except these ones:

- Humphreys-A course in group theory;
- John B. Fraleigh-A First Course in Abstract Algebra;
- Hungerford’s Algebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try 'Abstract Algebra' by Dummit and Foote. Everything in the book is written in detail but not with solution. There are plenty of examples.

But for the solution you have to search on internet.

Answer (score 3):

I used these notes after taking a year of undergraduate algebra and things finally made sense,  [Abstract Algebra Notes](http://fmwww.bc.edu/gross/MT216/aata.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It's already been mentioned, but I would like to second Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra, Third Edition*. It is remarkably well-written. It manages to strike a perfect balance between being terse where possible and deeply informative where needed. It's a perfect resource not only for group actions, but pretty much any topic in a typical abstract algebra course.

Answer (score 2):

If you are specifically interested in permutation groups and group actions, you should read Permutation Groups by Dixon and Mortimer.  It is much more advanced than general texts on abstract algebra and group theory and discusses primitive permutation groups in detail (including the [O'Nan Scott theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Nan%E2%80%93Scott_theorem)).  This is useful if you are interested in using permutation groups in other areas such as computational group theory.

Depending on how much you want to know, it may be overkill, but the first few chapters would still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite textbook is the "Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications" by Judson available for free [here](http://abstract.ups.edu/).